# Different result of Traversal

Tags: neo4j

Traversal API is giving different result for seemingly same declaration. In method 1. I took method 1 sample from neo4j's site. And tried to restructure it in method 2. However, apparently there is not difference, both methods are producing different output. Method2 is completely skipping LIKE relationship. Even if I change the sequence in method1 like putting `depthFirst()` in last, the output changes.

It will be great if someone could please help me understand this different output?

**Method 1:**

```
void depthFirst() {

        GraphDatabaseBuilder graphDbBuilder = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(storeDir);

        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = graphDbBuilder.newGraphDatabase();

        String output = "";
        int i = 0;

        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Node node = graphDb.findNode(LabelTyeps.Person, "name", "Joe");

            for (Path position : graphDb.traversalDescription().depthFirst()
                    .relationships(RelationshipTypes.KNOWS)
                    .relationships(RelationshipTypes.LIKES, Direction.INCOMING)
                    .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(5)).traverse(node)) {

                output += position.toString() + ":"
                        + (String) position.endNode().getProperty("name")
                        + "\n";
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }
```

Output of method 1:

```
(3):Joe
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8):Lisa
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8)--[KNOWS,2]-->(4):Lars
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8)--[KNOWS,2]-->(4)--[KNOWS,4]-->(7):Dirk
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8)--[KNOWS,2]-->(4)--[KNOWS,4]-->(7)--[KNOWS,5]-->(6):Peter
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8)--[KNOWS,2]-->(4)--[KNOWS,4]-->(7)--[KNOWS,5]-->(6)--[KNOWS,7]-->(5):Sara
(3)<--[LIKES,1]--(8)--[KNOWS,2]-->(4)<--[KNOWS,3]--(9):Ed
```

**Method 2** (Just changed the way travDesc is structured)

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Node node = graphDb.findNode(LabelTyeps.Person, "name", "Joe");

            TraversalDescription travDesc = graphDb.traversalDescription();
            travDesc.depthFirst();
            travDesc.relationships(RelationshipTypes.KNOWS);
            travDesc.relationships(RelationshipTypes.LIKES, Direction.INCOMING);

            travDesc.evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(5));

            for (Path position : travDesc.traverse(node)) {

                // System.out.println("Loop count: " + ++i);
                output += position.toString() + ":"
                        + (String) position.endNode().getProperty("name")
                        + "\n";
                // System.out.println(output);

            }
            System.out.println(output);

        }
```

Output of method 2

```
(3):Joe
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5):Sara
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)<--[KNOWS,7]--(6):Peter
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)<--[KNOWS,7]--(6)<--[KNOWS,5]--(7):Dirk
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)<--[KNOWS,7]--(6)<--[KNOWS,5]--(7)<--[KNOWS,4]--(4):Lars
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)<--[KNOWS,7]--(6)<--[KNOWS,5]--(7)<--[KNOWS,4]--(4)<--[KNOWS,3]--(9):Ed
(3)--[KNOWS,6]-->(5)<--[KNOWS,7]--(6)<--[KNOWS,5]--(7)<--[KNOWS,4]--(4)<--[KNOWS,2]--(8):Lisa
```

**Sample data:**

```
create (:Person {name:"Joe"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Lars"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Sara"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Peter"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Dirk"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Lisa"})
 ,(:Person{name:"Ed"})

 match (a:Person{name:"Lisa"}), (b:Person{name:"Joe"}) create (a) - [:LIKES] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Lisa"}), (b:Person{name:"Lars"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Ed"}), (b:Person{name:"Lars"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Lars"}), (b:Person{name:"Dirk"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Dirk"}), (b:Person{name:"Peter"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Joe"}), (b:Person{name:"Sara"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
 match (a:Person{name:"Peter"}), (b:Person{name:"Sara"}) create (a) - [:KNOWS] -> (b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TraversalDescription` is a immutable fluent API, quoting form http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/TraversalDescription.html

> A traversal description is immutable and each method which adds or modifies the behavior returns a new instances that includes the new modification, leaving the instance which returns the new instance intact.